# Usefulness of [443]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just noticed there is a [443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/443) tag. It is used in more than a handful of questions, but I find its name quite poorly chosen.

What to do about it? Rename? Remove?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've gone with @kasperd 's suggestion and synonymized, then merged [443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/443) to [port-443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port-443).

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

My initial thought upon reading the question was that 443 was a rarely used HTTP status code. It turns out that's not what it was used for. Which proves your point about the naming being extremely poor.

I agree that [port-443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port-443) would be much better. I don't have much opinion on whether renaming or creating both names with [443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/443) being a synonym for [port-443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port-443) is the better choice.

Merging with [https](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/https) or simply deleting [443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/443) would also be better than status-quo.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest we merge the tag with [HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/https).
The current description already says "AKA HTTPS"...

And we might as well merge [port-80](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port-80) with [HTTP](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http).

Comment: I'd like to do that, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Who would be do that then?

Comment: @glglgl A mod could do that, but I'm not sure they ought to be merged.  I see at least one question with the 443 tag which is specifically about port 443, and not about the https protocol.  They are separate things, after all. Even if port 443 was only ever used for the https protocol, the port and the protocol are not the same thing.

Comment: @HopelessN00b But perhaps those few cases where 443 was used to only talk about the port, and not the protocol behind it, would be better served tagged as [port](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port).

Comment: @HopelessN00b At least the tag is very badly named. 443 could be everything; there is [tag:port-80] which is by far better named.