# What bad tags in need of burnination do we still have hanging around?

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request, burninate-request

[Similar to the old "bad tag collection" thread](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3042/118258), I'm looking for suggestions/submissions of tags we still have hanging around on Server Fault, that we would be better off not having in existence anymore, because they're no longer on topic ([career](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career)), [because they should be merged into something else](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/7869/118258) ([443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/443)), or because they just plain suck so much it's painful ([fixed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fixed)).

I'm also looking for tags that are a mess and need cleanup, but not might not need destroyed ([documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/documentation)).

Either way, questions that are locked for historical significance can be ♦-edited (therefore, retagged) without bumping them to the top of the active list... so I'll be temporarily locking questions I retag to minimize disruptions.

I've also created a new tag, [historical](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/historical) to help me deal with questions that don't really have a valid, on-topic tag that's applicable to them anymore.

Like the older bad tag older thread, the idea is to consolidate a bunch of retag/burninate requests into one, and this also allows me track tags I wish to kill off easily, without having hundreds of open browser tabs devoted to the purpose.

And of course, if anyone thinks a tag that I'm working on shouldn't be destroyed or cleaned up, that feedback is welcome as well.  Post answers however you like - one tag per answer, multiple tags per answer, whatever - and I'll come by and add suggested tags to my list of tags to look into.

---

**A couple notes to anyone who wants to search out tags in need of being killed off:**

- Tags that **actually** have 0 questions are automatically deleted by a script daily.

  - Tags with locked questions in them aren't affected by the deletion script.
- The individual page for a given tag (such as https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career) may ***lie*** to you!

  - [image]
  - [image]
- The default page for all tags is also a filthy, filthy liar.

  - [image]

    - The small, grey number to the side of a tag indicates the number of questions a tag has, but doesn't count the number of *locked* questions in that tag.
    - Tags without a number either have 0 unlocked questions in them, or aren't actually tags, but are synonyms.

---

## Tags that I'm currently working on getting rid of:

[upload](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/upload)[usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/usage)[easyapache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/easyapache)[scheduling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scheduling)[requirements](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requirements)[centralization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/centralization)[document-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/document-management)[wildcard](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wildcard)[failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/failed)[device](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/device)[path](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/path)[persistence](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/persistence)[response-time](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/response-time)[undo](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/undo)[analysis](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/analysis)[analytics](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/analytics)[block](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/block)[checklist](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/checklist)[color](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/color)[controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/controller)[customization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/customization)[diagnostic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/diagnostic)[editor](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/editor)[extract](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/extract)[filenames](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filenames)[filter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filter)[fonts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fonts)[interrupts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/interrupts)[library](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/library)[limits](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/limits)[mapping](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mapping)[media](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/media)[mirror](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mirror)[program](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/program)[remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote)[resume](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/resume)[tagging](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tagging)[task](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/task)[theory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/theory)[upload](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/upload)[twitter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/twitter)[options](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/options)[thrashing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/thrashing)[open-iscsi](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/open-iscsi)[shares](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/shares)[remove](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remove)[lag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lag)[imagick](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/imagick)[virtuozzo](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtuozzo)[setenv](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/setenv)[setenvif](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/setenvif)[local-system](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/local-system)[design](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/design)[cost-savings](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cost-savings)[sort](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sort)[indexing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/indexing)[create](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/create)[keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/keys)[paypal](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/paypal)[page](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/page)[collision](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/collision)[span](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/span)[soa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soa)

## Tags that I'm currently cleaning up:

[password](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/password)[documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/documentation)[maintenance](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/maintenance)[upgrading](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/upgrading)[troubleshooting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting)[small-business](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business)[infrastructure](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure)[debugging](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debugging)[testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/testing)[user-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/user-management)[daemon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/daemon)[configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/configuration)[administrator](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/administrator)[licensing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/licensing)[web](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/web)[directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/directory)[files](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/files)[optimization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/optimization)[port](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port)[process](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/process)[service](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/service)[startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/startup)[users](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/users)[application](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/application)[automation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/automation)[boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/boot)[package](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/package)[packaging](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/packaging)[remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote)[replication](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/replication)[testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/testing)[video](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/video)[vulnerabilities](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vulnerabilities)[install](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/install)[timeout](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/timeout)[virtual](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual)[rackmount](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rackmount)[imaging](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/imaging)[image](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/image)[images](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/images)

---

Comment: Also a bit off-topic perhaps. But I think the name for the `historical` tag is a bit odd. Tags generally refer to the question they are placed under, and the tag gives the impression that the question is historical. Maybe `tagless` would be a better fit? Nit-picking here.

Comment: @Reaces Also a valid point.  I'll put some thought into a better name for that tag.

Comment: Cleanup tag suggestion: [tag:method]

Comment: @Reaces Looks like a thoroughly useless tag to me. I'll get it burninated today.

Comment: [tag:xampp], [tag:wamp] [tag:mamp] are sewers especially in conjunction with [tag:localhost]

Comment: [thrashing](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/thrashing) is surely a candidate

Comment: [accessibility](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) is a pretty dirty tag as well.(And for some reason [access](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/access) seems weird as well, but I can't really say why... maybe its because I'm not natively english)

Comment: Just out of curiosity,  what's difference between cleaning up and getting rid of? Is getting rid of === burninating?

Comment: @masegaloeh Mostly.  Cleaning up is for tags that might be salvageable, and might stay around.  Getting a tag deleted by removing it from every question is what I mean by getting rid of.  An automatic tag deletion by a developer is a burnination.

Comment: Can you explain *your* procedure to deleting the bad tags? From my observation, looks like (1) you synonymized/merged the list of **off-topic-tags** likes webmin, cpanel or plesk to single [off-topic tag](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/off-topic).  The next step is: (2) for bad/low-quality question you locked/closed the and for good question you remove the off-topic tag from the question. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this thread is still being actively pursued, however I would like to submit [address](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/address) as being a down-right horrible mixture of IP-Address Mac-Address and other addresses.

Answer (score 5):

By extending [Jeff Ferland](http://meta.serverfault.com/users/3139) query from [top 100](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/59684/top-tags-by-closed-question-ratio) to [top 300](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/revision/267129/348916/top-tags-by-closed-question-ratio), here some tags that I'm proposing

- Nuked tags because off-topic: [suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/suggestions)[alternatives-to](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/alternatives-to)[gotchas](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gotchas)
- Cleanup tags (similar with [documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/documentation)): [reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reference)[guides](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/guides)
- Gray area:

  - [setting-as-default](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/setting-as-default): some questions about how to make an option as default option for client
  - [select](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/select): 5 Questions about how `select` query affect DB performance. Maybe better in SO or DBA.SE. But it falls to [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) because this tag commonly means different things to different people.

<sub>Still updating...</sub>

Answer (score 3):

[golang](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/golang) should be merged into [go](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/go) (or synonymized).

Answer (score 3):

[soa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soa) is a mixture of [soa-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soa-record) and [Oracle Service-Oriented-Architecture.](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/soa/enterprise-repository/overview/index.html).
It should probably be made a synonym of [soa-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soa-record) and the Oracle questions have the tag removed.

Comment: For that matter, SOA-record should probably be merged into one of the tags for DNS zones. Good eye... I'll have to think about the whole SOA thing for a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think [loops](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/loops) should go. Perhaps [localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/localhost) isn't particularly valuable either. (If both of those flags are eliminated, it would leave one question without any labels at all.)

Comment: If there are no tags in the question because of burninated-tag-ritual or deleted by system (because of 6 months inactivity), then the question will be tagged with special tag: `untagged`

Answer (score 1):

After some hiatus because of [duplicate tags hunting](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7937/cleanup-duplicate-tags-different-by-hyphenation-and-pluralization?lq=1), here the proposed bad tag (again)

- [www](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/www) Bunch of question where user wants his website accessible for both www and non-www version
- [bypass](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bypass) **Most** of the question was about bypassing some restriction in their environment
- [freeware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/freeware) Question about: what's best freeware to do blablabla...
- Others:[dropbox](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dropbox)[pictures](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pictures)

[Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) collection

[global](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/global)[category](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/category)[custom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/custom)[dual](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dual)[kits](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kits)[stop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/stop)[distro](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/distro)[defininition](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/defininition)[text](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/text)[preference](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/preference)

Duplicate tags collection

- [conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/conf) ->  [configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/configuration)
- [cals](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cals) ->  [cal](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cal)
- [home](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home) ->  [home-directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-directory)

<sub>Still updating...</sub>