# Reopen locked question

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

I stumbled across a [inspircd authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/271625/irc-restricting-all-user-functionality-until-authentication-inspircd?s=1%7C1.2840) question which is locked so  answers, comments, edits are restricted. The link in the sole (accepted) answer can't even be updated to point at the current version of the docs.

I'd like to reopen, refine the question to a less vague "how can I implement user authentication with inspircd?" and provide a more comprehensive answer with links to authentication modules in addition to sqlauth module linked in the answer from 2011.

I know I could ask and answer a new question but I'd prefer to improve a dated poor quality question rather than have the site littered with unmaintained outdated content. This question wasn't spam, an unintelligible question or a lightning rod for vandalism, I don't see the benefit of closing and locking a question four years after its asked/answered. It ensures it's *only* ever of "historical significance" because it can't ever be updated/improved.

Fixing an outdated link feels like something which should be facilitated, even on a locked question.  Is there any way for an average user (sub 3k rep) to bring attention to a locked question short of a meta post like this? If so, can we update help pages for the [close questions privilege](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/close-questions), it suggested two  alternatives for users who lack the "vote to open/close" privilege, neither of which are unavailable on locked questions (one can neither flag nor comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't even tell why that question was locked to begin with. So I've unlocked it. Have a ball.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question and provided an updated answer.  It appears this question was originally locked by @HopelessN00b which is a whole other can of worms I have no interest in rehashing. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8071/some-parting-thoughts-and-apologies-for-the-drama