# Why is HopelessN00b stalking me?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, moderators, tagging

Why is HopelessN00b stalking me and mass-closing my questions?

[image: closed questions pic]

Comment: [I'm HopelessN00b, and I approve this message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxiu5.png). A meta topic about me being a jerk is probably a good thing to have around to point people at.  Better yet, maybe we need to add something to the SeverFault tour.  ~`Warning, beware of N00b!  N00b WILL bite`.

Comment: @HopelessN00b We can even make this a canonical question!

Answer (score 21):

I wouldn't take it personally.  I have it on good authority that the guy's just a prick.

But, he's a prick who's going through a [massive tag cleanup effort at the moment](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/7934/118258), so he probably bumped into a group of your old questions because of their tags.

I'd venture a guess that upon reviewing those questions with the site's current topicality rules in mind, he closed them because it was appropriate to do so.  I bet he also retagged them, and even went through the effort of (temporarily) locking them so them didn't get bumped to the top of the active view and end up mass-downvoted.

For a guy who's such a jerk, that was uncharacteristically thoughtful of him, I think.

Comment: ZOMG!  The power has gone to your head and the site is doomed!  Doomed! I tell you!  All the warnings were correct!!!!!

Comment: @Ward Hey, you guys have no one to blame but yourselves. Not like every other Stack Exchange employee didn't warn you. :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWdfRRtAs3o  ;)

Comment: One downvote, I wonder where that came from.