# Tag reverse is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-burnination

The [reverse](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse) tag has been used with at least three different meanings. Reverse DNS, reverse proxy, reverse port-forwarding.

I think the tag needs to go. Should it just be removed, or should questions first be re-tagged?

More appropriate tags to use instead include: [reverse-proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy) [reverse-dns](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns) [ptr-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ptr-record)

Answer (score 6):

I definitely agree that it's a bad tag, and should be burnt to a crisp and banned from ever being used again.  Some of the questions it is on are already reasonably tagged, but others need to be retagged a bit to maintain a reasonable amount of clarity (for example, questions tagged [reverse](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse) and [proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/proxy) should probably have both those tags removed and replaced with [reverse-proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy)).

Being a shiny new mod, I'm not sure how best to do those edits without bubbling all those questions up to the top of active, so I'll not commit to doing it myself (unless a more senior mod wishes to instruct me in the necessary arcane arts...)

Comment: This doesn't need mod powers. One of the issues Josh had with he Noob was lack of community involvement in the great burnination - apparently the community should be enlisted to help get the job done.

Comment: In order to do it without spamming the active tab it needs mod powers, right?  Many moons ago I got in trouble for doing a mass-retagging-by-edit because it spammed the active tab.  Perhaps we don't care about that as much any more?  I'm also not seeing a way to "blacklist" a tag... is that not a thing (any more?), or have I just not found the right page to do it?

Comment: SOP so as not to spam the front page is to do  few, wait a while, then do some more. You could also gather the community together at a convenient time and do it - perhaps at a weekend when the river of crap is less dilute and the chance of missing a quality question is lower. The important thing is community involvement*.  It will stop Josh and the SO team from thinking you are a bot, panicking, and taking your ♦ away from you.

Comment: My preciousssss...

Comment: @womble I'll start editing some of the tags out of existence, you can duly consider me `community involvment` in this one.

Comment: Schweet.  I'll hit the odd one when while I'm waiting for my builds to finish.

Comment: @womble I decided to slow down a bit, as it better fits my work schedule and is kinder to the front page. I'm doing two every 30ish minutes. Mostly the blatant ones for now.

Comment: @womble In order to clean up tags without spamming the front page you need to bribe a CM or Developer to fiddle with the database - otherwise for retagging the general rule is like Iain said: Community consensus and try not to flood the front page with tag changes :)

Comment: (also I believe tag/content blacklisting still requires CM intervention too, but generally if we get rid of the "bad" tag it won't come back as it won't be auto-suggested anymore)

Comment: He Lives !!!1!!

Comment: I'll work on it, too.

Comment: ...and the very first question I found was a request for products. I think doing these kinds of clean-ups are also a good time to evaluate the topicality of the questions for the site as it currently exists.

Comment: @womble, Yeah you're right. The mod privileges can be used for mass retagging. With the [locked-question method](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7880/what-bad-tags-in-need-of-burnination-do-we-still-have-hanging-around), our ex-mod *noob* can retag hundred of questions without spamming our precious frontpage

Comment: One left, but it needs a shiny diamond: http://serverfault.com/questions/232083/how-typically-reverse-proxy

Comment: Odd... I'm not sure why that one needed shiny-diamond powers (perhaps because it was a migration reject), but I've fixed it up.  The reverse tag is gone!  Top work by everyone who contributed to making it happen.

Comment: @womble Your shiny diamond is also needed to put up the [tag:status-completed] on this thread.