# Tag "remote" is ridiculous

Tags: discussion, tag-burnination

Similar to kasperd's recent observation that [the 'reverse' tag is ambiguous](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8348/1375), I'd like to solicit additional opinions about [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote), which recently came to my attention because someone proposed a tag wiki entry for it.

Anyone think that [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) shouldn't go the same way as [reverse](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse), with a gradual re-tagging with more appropriate alternatives?  [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) appears to be the one that people most often miss, and in many other cases the tag just doesn't add anything at all and can be deleted.

Answer (score 20):

I agree that [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) by itself is not a useful tag name. Of 451 questions currently tagged [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) 36 of them are also tagged [desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/desktop). I guess most of those 36 should be tagged [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) rather than [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) and [desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/desktop).

Of the other 415 questions tagged [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) without the [desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/desktop) tag, it is likely there are also some that should be tagged [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop), but it doesn't look like the majority.

Some of the questions with the [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) tag are also tagged [ssh](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ssh). In those cases I would say that [ssh](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ssh) implies remote access, and the [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) tag is redundant and can be removed.

But there are questions such as [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/716730/dell-supplemental-pack-xenserver-6-5) about remotely power cycling hardware, which is tagged [remote](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote) and none of the other tags directly implies remote access.

A question like that might need a new tag to indicate that it is about performing such an operation remotely. That is unless we consider performing system administration remotely so inherent to this site, that we don't need a tag for it.

The tags [desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/desktop) and [local](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/local) which I found on some of the questions also sound like they are not very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the additional, in-depth analysis.  Funny that there are questions which are simultaneously both "local" *and* "remote"...